# android opengl es 1.1 texture compression on the fly

Tags: android, opengl-es, compression, textures

i have to use texture compression as my app is currently using up to 100MB of ram for textures.

i am creating textures from Views, so it is not possible for them to be created in a compressed format. how can i compress them with ETC1/ATC/PVRTC on the fly and send them to gpu? i tried:

```
GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, ETC1.ETC1_RGB8_OES, bitmap, 0);
```

i also tried other compression formats supported by my phone, but the texture is always white. the input bitmap is an RGB_565 and mip-maps are disabled.

is it possible to send a bitmap as a texture to opengl es 1.1 so it gets automatically compressed on android, like it is possible on a pc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

with help from Arne Bergene Fossaa i get to this solution:

```
int size = m_TexBitmap.getRowBytes() * m_TexBitmap.getHeight();
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(size); // size is good
bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
m_TexBitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(bb);
bb.position(0);

ETC1Texture etc1tex;
// RGB_565 is 2 bytes per pixel
//ETC1Texture etc1tex = ETC1Util.compressTexture(bb, m_TexWidth, m_TexHeight, 2, 2*m_TexWidth);

final int encodedImageSize = ETC1.getEncodedDataSize(m_TexWidth, m_TexHeight);
ByteBuffer compressedImage = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(encodedImageSize).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
// RGB_565 is 2 bytes per pixel
ETC1.encodeImage(bb, m_TexWidth, m_TexHeight, 2, 2*m_TexWidth, compressedImage);
etc1tex = new ETC1Texture(m_TexWidth, m_TexHeight, compressedImage);

//ETC1Util.loadTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, GL10.GL_RGB, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5, etc1tex);
gl.glCompressedTexImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, ETC1.ETC1_RGB8_OES, m_TexWidth, m_TexHeight, 0, etc1tex.getData().capacity(), etc1tex.getData());

bb = null;
compressedImage = null;
etc1tex = null;
```

i know about the *ETC1Util.compressTexture* and *ETC1Util.loadTexture*, but they were giving corrupted textures. good thing is that i went from 100MB down to 26MB with native memory consumption. but this solution is slow as hell. and even though it is done on a separate thread with min priority, the rendering thread is totally blocked. is there a more efficent way? or do i have to create these ETC1 textures on the first run on a new device and save them to SD card for later reuse?

Comment: Distribute the compressed textures with your app as assets, there is no need to compress them on the device except if they are dynamically generated.

Comment: @fabspro they are dynamically generated based on device's resolution and capabilities. fortunatelly only once, when the app is started for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that through OpenGL ES - only ETC decompression is supported. ETC compression is not really trivial to do fast and good - you might have a look at http://devtools.ericsson.com/etc and implement etcpack in your program, though.

Comment: other compressions (ATC/PVRTC) are also not possible in this way? the etcpack is for windows and i need it to run on an android device. so the only way is to create a texture from View, then with ETC1Util compress it and save it on SD card for later reuse?

Comment: Yes, this is the case for all compressed textures, there is no builtin support in GL to compress them. You do not have to save it to the SD card of course, you can upload the ETC texture at once.